# Cutting a surface mesh

Tags: 3d, mesh, point-clouds, meshlab

Is there any way to slice a surface mesh along a plane using Meshlab?  Or select all the triangles of a surface mesh that are below a plane?

I want to delete all of the faces of a surface mesh that are below 0 in the z-axis.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot slice a mesh with the current release (2016.12), however this enhancement should be implemented in the "Compute Planar Section" filter next release, see [issue #118](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/issues/118). Alternatively, you could use Blender's "bisect" tool, which can do this.

It is possible to select all the vertices or faces below a plane and delete them using "Conditional Face Selection" or "Conditional Vertex Selection"; followed by a delete command. For vertex selection, you would use something like `x < 0` in the filter.